# error C2664: 'MessageBoxA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::string' to 'LPCSTR'

Tags: c++, winapi

I tried this in c++:

```
std::string teststring = "hello";
MessageBox(NULL,teststring,NULL, NULL);
```

error C2664: 'MessageBoxA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::string' to 'LPCSTR'

Comment: The last parameter isn't even a pointer, yet you pass `NULL`.

Comment: @chris Well, NULL actually works. I don't have a problem with it if it works.

Comment: So does 0 or `MB_OK`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it looks like Visual C++ so tag it properly.

You can get the inside buffer using c_str() method on a std::string, so your code becomes:

```
std::string teststring = "hello";
MessageBox(NULL,teststring.c_str(),NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: why visual C++? you could use any C++ compiler here. However answer is correct )

Comment: Yes, but normally in Windows environment when you are using a Windows API (MessageBox), most probably you are on Visual C++. That's why I said, 'it looks like'

Answer (score 1):

**MessageBox's** second and third parameter expect a **C string**.

To get a C string from a **std::string** you call [c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str), therefor the correct way to call it is:

```
std::string teststring = "hello";
MessageBox(NULL, teststring.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

what about try this?

```
std::string teststring = "hello";
LPCSTR tmp = teststring .c_str()
MessageBox(NULL,tmp ,NULL, NULL);
```